# MS Access Input Mask for Postcode

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, validation

Is there a way to set an input mask in MS Access 2007 so that certain elements are optional? UK postcodes can be in a number of formats: `LL00 0LL` or `L00 0LL` or even `LL00 L00LL`. For this particular assignment, I need only worry about the first two formats.

So, is there a way for me to set the input mask so that the first letter is optional?

Comment: not that I'm aware of out-of-the-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer [here](http://www.keystonelearning.com/resources/articles/access_2007_using_input_masks) and can just use the following:

`LA0# oLL`

`A` defines a letter or digit and `#` defines a digit or a space and removes the space when inserted into database.

Comment: Good find. Accept your answer and it will close the question.

Comment: Will do, as soon as it lets me. :)

Comment: For me I found this to be good working for UK postcodes:
`>LA&&a0LL`

It should cover postcodes like `N9 2JH, N10 2JH, NW10 2JH, NW9 2JH, WC2E 9RZ, W1H 2JH, W10H 2JH` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother.  Just use a text field and let the users insert the blanks.   Put some code in checking for approriate alphabetic vs numeric characters.

The advntage is this approach will work for any country.